# Linq Reflection Expression throws exception on property of proprety

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I'm trying to make functions with Linq Expressions arguments and am stuck on a problem.

Here's my test function:

```
public static void OutputField(Person p, Expression<Func<Person, string>> outExpr)
{
    var expr = (MemberExpression)outExpr.Body;
    var prop = (PropertyInfo)expr.Member;
    string v = prop.GetValue(p, null).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"value={v}");
}
```

If I define a Person object as

```
public class Person
{
    public PersonName Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class PersonName
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

and try to use it this way

```
Person person = new Person
{
    Name = new PersonName { First = "John", Last = "Doe" },
    City = "New York City"
};

OutputField(person, m => m.City);
OutputField(person, m => m.Name.First);
```

The output of the property City works, but the output of the property First of the property Name throws a **System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'** error.  How do I make my test function work?

"Combine lambda expressions to retrieve nested values" pointed to by CSharpie seems to be addressing a similar question, but it's not clear how I would work the answer into my function.

Comment: The error is that you are passing `Person` into `prop.GetValue` when accessing `PersonName.First`. The method tries to get the property `First` from `Person` but can't any. You need to pass the correct object into `prop.GetValue`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not simply `public static void OutputField(Person p, Func<Person, string> outExpr) => Console.WriteLine($"value={outExpr(p)}");`?

Comment: @Klaus This is just the test function.  Eventually, I'll want to be both getting and setting the property identified in the expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine lambda expressions to retrieve nested values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22378852/combine-lambda-expressions-to-retrieve-nested-values)

Comment: @Andrew I want to be able to specify my expressions relative to the top object.  Klaus's code lets me do this, but I need something that going to allow me to both get and set values.  I use this property of a property notation all the time when I call helper functions in my ASP.NET MVC views, e.g. TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name.First), which use Expressions, so I know it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you are passing `Person` into `prop.GetValue` when accessing `PersonName.First`. The method tries to get the property `First` from `Person` but can't any. You need to pass the correct object into `prop.GetValue`. I made this generic method which achives what you want. One limitation is that it only checks fields and properties, i will try to add methods in a bit

```
public static void OutputField < T > (T item, Expression < Func < T, string >> outExpr) 
{
  // Get the expression as string
  var str = outExpr.ToString();

  // Get the variable of the expresion (m, m => ...)
  string pObj = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(' '));

  // Get all the members in the experesion (Name, First | m.Name.First);
  string[] members = new string(str.Skip(pObj.Length * 2 + 5).ToArray()).Split('.');

  // Last object in the tree
  object lastMember = item;
  // The type of lastMember
  Type lastType = typeof(T);

  // Loop thru each member in members
  for (int i = 0; i < members.Length; i++) 
  {
    // Get the property value
    var prop = lastType.GetProperty(members[i]);
    // Get the field value
    var field = lastType.GetField(members[i]);

    // Get the correct one and set it as last member
    if (prop is null) 
    {
      lastMember = field.GetValue(lastMember);
    }
    else 
    {
      lastMember = prop.GetValue(lastMember, null);
    }

    // Set the type of the last member
    lastType = lastMember.GetType();
  }

  // Print the value
  Console.WriteLine($ "value={lastMember}");
}
```

**EDIT:**
Turns out you can compile the expression and invoke it

```
public static void OutputField<T>(T item, Expression<Func<T, string>> outExpr)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"value={outExpr.Compile().Invoke(item)}");
}
```

Comment: That works.  Now, any idea how to set the value?

Comment: In the loop, you can check if it is the last iteration and set the value of the Property / Field.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, I like the simplicity of the Compile/Invoke.  I marking this as the accepted answer.  I did figure out how to do a set and have shown it in the next answer.  I'm looking for a way to simplify the set.

Comment: Instead of `outExpr.Compile().Invoke(item)`, you can use `outExpr.Compile()(item)`. That is because if `f` is a `Func<,>`, you can invoke it simply as `f(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I cam up with based on @Andrew's answer for the get and some other code I found for the get.  I'm not sure if there is an equivalent simpler way to do the set.

```
public static void OutputField<T>(T p, Expression<Func<T, string>> get)
{
    // get the value
    string v = get.Compile().Invoke(p).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine($"retrieved value={v}");

    // set a value
    var expr = (MemberExpression)get.Body;
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "value");
    var set = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, string>>(Expression.Assign(expr, param), get.Parameters[0], param);
    var action = set.Compile();
    action(p, "a new value");
}
```